# Unable to show/hide using Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Following some examples Ive seen, I am trying to be able to click to show/hide a Div ID. Content is hidden but when I click AFC Playoff Race,
nothing happens. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

CSS Style sheet includes:

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
.unhidden { visibility: visible; }
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
      item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="panel panel-afc nopad playoffs">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <a href="javascript:unhide('afc-playoff-container');" rel="nofollow">AFC Playoffs</a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="afc-playoff-container" class="hidden">
      <div id="afc playoff">
        <table class="data-table1" border="0" width="100%"></table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `<table` is missing the `>`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Do you have `hidden`/`unhidden` css classes defined in your css style sheets?

Comment: that is not CSS is HTML...

Comment: Yes, its typo.  Yes, .hidden and .unhidden are in the Stylesheet.

Comment: Do your elements have actual content? If not than you will not actually see anything being hidden/shown as divs and tables by default do not have visual borders, backgrounds etc

Comment: It works, but your table is empty. So you don't see anything. Fill the table and it works......

Comment: @Refilon  The table grabs data from somewhere else. So thats why I dont have it defined with content. I tried Dinindu's code  , it takes me to the top of the page but doesnt display. Look here, on the left side youll see AFC Playoffs. That is clickable. But it wont show the content like you would see similar to whats shown for NFC Playoffs.  Www.daddyleagues.com/madscrubs

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you make a working stack snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function unhide() {
  var item = document.querySelector(this.dataset.target);
  if (item) {
    item.classList.toggle('hidden');
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var toggleDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('toggleDiv');
  if (toggleDivs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < toggleDivs.length; i++) {
      toggleDivs[i].addEventListener('click', unhide);
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#afc-playoff-container {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-afc nopad playoffs">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="toggleDiv" data-target='#afc-playoff-container' rel="nofollow">AFC Playoffs</a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="afc-playoff-container" class="hidden">
      <div id="afc playoff">
        <table class="data-table1" border="0" width="100%"></table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no joy. The table grabs data from somewhere else. So thats why I dont have it defined with content. When I try your code, it takes me to the top of the page but doesnt display. Look here, on the left side youll see AFC Playoffs. That is clickable. But it wont show the content like you would see similar to whats shown for NFC Playoffs.  Www.daddyleagues.com/madscrubs

Comment: When you get a chance can you see my response and check out the page?

Comment: Youre the best DININDU. Thank you so much!

Comment: One last thing. Is it possible to use this code for div id's with the same name? From testing it, it seems to not control more than one Div ID. I have another ID with same name, but it does not show/hide.

Comment: @jack213. That's why i use it with class

Answer (score 1):

It works, you just didn't apply styles to the classes `hidden` and `unhidden`. See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/ianm/pen/GZwLjX) for what I mean.

Good luck!

Comment: Include code examples directly into your answers, links can rot and users shouldn't have to go to a external site to see it.